# Procedure for making GUI based applications

Tags: java, user-interface, optimization, coding-style

**Is there any method to be followed before writing code for a GUI program?
 For previous programs, i had algorithm and/or class diagrams before writing code for the normal programs(those done before learning GUI)

Should we follow anything similar while making GUI?**

I just made a small game(Book cricket) which involves using data stored in files and some computations.
I have completed the game just by making one thing at a time and so, i have lots of code. I just wanted to know if there is any procedure while making GUI based applications that can be followed for optimizing and making the code easy to read and debug?

To be more specific:
**1**. Should we design all panels in different classes?
**2**. If there are actionListeners for the objects, then should i put them along with the creation of the objects?
**3**. While using cardLayout to manage which panel should be visible, i often had to convert all the fields related to a panel static so that i could modify fields in one panel on actionEvents in some other panel. 
Is this a standard thing to do or should i be doing something different.
**4**. I use the terminal to write my codes. Since i have just started working on GUI, i thought working with terminal would be a more better learning experience.Should i continue using terminal or switch to some IDE like eclipse/netBeans ???

Thanks

Comment: No special procedure, just experience. Don't expect yourself to write elegant/efficient code until you get enough of it. 2. Automatic gui builders are the worst friend for a learner. (and some would argue they're bad for the experienced as well).

Answer (score 1):

What kind of program does you want to write : it is a game or just an application ? For each kind of thing, often, there are patterns to do this. Moreover, for each kind of game or application, there are many ways to build framework. In other word, it's diversity, and depend well on program.

Nevertheless, in general way, there are some suggestion when you start to design your program. For example, you can apply MVC (Model-View-Controller) to this by :

**View** : this is a GUI and just a GUI. it contains code to build a GUI, build action listener for some objects such as buttons .... when some action appears on this GUI, for example, someone click a button, it will call appropriate action in Controller. So, View, in fact, doesn't really understand anything. It doesn't know (and doesn't care) this button or that button should do what.

**Controller** : connect between View and model. It will initialize View and Model. It will receive action from View, and call appropriate method from model and return result again to view. Controller knows how to control flow of data from user.

**Model** : a class with bunch of action that your application can do. Model doesn't really know, how to operate your program, it just holds the state of program.

Hope this help :)